# How to link a commit which has been pushed to GitHub to an issue?

Tags: git, github

I have pushed a commit to my repo. But I forgot to link it to an issue via adding `#<issue ID>` to the commit message. Can I link it to the issue by some approach I don't know on GitHub? Or I have to rewrite the history (amend the commit and push -f)?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the commit in a different branch from master or a different fork from the  repo where where issue was raised?

Comment: I usually paste the commit hash in a comment on the Issue. GitHub automatically creates a link out of the hash. It's reverse of what you are asking, but functionally solves the same problem of creating a link between the commit and the issue.

Comment: Thank you, @CollinBarrett. You solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually paste the commit hash in a comment on the Issue. GitHub automatically creates a link out of the hash. It's reverse of what you are asking, but functionally solves the same problem of creating a link between the commit and the issue.